# NA value in portfolio sorts

Tags: r, statistics, finance, portfolio, economics

I am currently doing portfolio sorts on panel data meaning every month I form 5 portfolios based on the volatility of stocks. I have the following function:

```
arguments are
x: a vector of returns 
P: the number of portfolios we want
sortPort <- function(x, P=5) {
# determine the breakpoints of the sorting variable
b <- quantile(x, 0:P/P, na.rm=TRUE)
  # assign a portfolio-number to each stock-observation in a particular month
p <- cut(x, breaks=b, labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)
# return the portfolio-number and add a "p" in front
return(paste0("p",p))
}
```

After forming the portfolios I am calculating the mean returns each month.

```
apply sortPort function to each month (by=mdate) separately
using the ivol as a sorting variable
only use months, where ivol is not missing (!is.na)
#d[!is.na(IVOL_t1),ivolport:=sortPort(IVOL_t1),by=mdate]

# calculate (equal weighted) portfolio returns for each of the 5 portfolios in           each month
ivolret.long <-     d[!is.na(IVOL_t1),list(port.return=mean(ret)),keyby=list(ivolport,mdate)]

convert from long to wide format
ivolret.wide <- dcast.data.table(ivolret.long, formula="mdate~ivolport", value.var="port.return")
```

My problem now is that I have NA values in ivolret.wide looking like this

```
mdate p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
1      1  2  3  4  5
2      1  2  3  4  5
3      NA  2  NA  4  5
4      1  NA  3  NA  5
```

How is that even possible? Only when all stocks in bucket in time 3 would have a return of 0, right? Is there a way to test this?

I hope you understand my question!

Answer (score 0):

The learning curve is steep in R and I know get my mistake. I had some NA in my column for returns and therefor this happened.